# What NiFi processor should I be using to filter out data from 2 groups and merge back into one?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I'm working on a flow which I documented the idea behind but have run into an issue where I cannot seem to find the processor to handle this.

What is happening is the input port is fed many files which based on data splits to A or B. A has more data within a file that gets split out to multiple flows and for each of the flows I set an ID found in the data. At the end I need to compare A to B and B to A and only keep what is found not to exist in the other group.

I have attached a diagram where you'll see at the bottom where I need to

1. Filter out of Group A any ids matched to Group B
2. Filter out of Group B any ids matched to Group A
3. Gather what remains and send it on its way for additional stuff

**Question #1.** Does NiFi support this kind of action?

**Question #2.** What processor can do this comparison?

**Question #3.** Also, I'm using the Wait at the end right before the compare to make sure I have all the data before I would send it to be compared. But thinking about that how do I make sure the comparison gets the data from both sides when A and B have all the data and not just A or B completes on the Wait?

[image: NiFi Comparison Flow]

Comment: Sounds like a join in SQL server. I think you should store both databsets into some storage and make join...

Comment: @daggett You mean to store the data into temp tables into a database and then SQL it? Or is there a built in NiFi SQL like storage that I can store it into?

Comment: There is no sql-like storage in nifi. It holds only flowfiles in file-based queues.